# Delete your account?

Tags: support, user-accounts, deleted-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/can-i-delete-my-account)

Is there a way to delete my *photo.stackexchange.com* account?

Comment: You're welcome to ask questions about things that confuse you, but you've asked 9 questions in the last week and at least 6 of them are duplicates (not all have closed yet). Maybe you want to try poking through the [meta FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/)?

Comment: @Michael Mrozek: Ok, Thanks! I believe that this is the only question that has not closed yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

email team@stackoverflow.com and they will delete it for you...Include your account name, account URL, etc...

Comment: Thanks! Will accept your answer in 10 min.

Comment: for some reason, there is an email to team@stackoverflow.com and an email to team@stackexchange.com? so if one doesn't work, try the other...sorry about that.

Comment: And, before sending the email: [Edit your profile to say "please delete me"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/can-i-delete-my-account/7979#7979).

Comment: Each of the original trilogy has their own support email address; Meta, Stack Apps, and Careers share the address with Stack Overflow while Area 51 has its own exclusive area51(at)stackoverflow(dot)com. Then there's the general one to account for all of the Stack Exchange 2.0 sites. They are all managed by Stack Overflow Internet Services Inc., so you'll reach the right people no matter who you send to.